# How can I encapsulate a joined table's result entity inside another entity in Doctrine?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, pdo, doctrine-orm

The query works great, and in my old PDO-based code I was able to nest related table models within the parent model, when querying joined tables. Using this code:

```
$qry = $em->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('l', 'a')
            ->from('AppBundle:Hflogs', 'l')
            ->leftJoin('AppBundle:HflogSwLocations', 'a')
            ->where($em->createQueryBuilder()->expr()->notIn('l.id', $sub->getDQL()))
            ->orderBy('l.submitted', 'DESC')
            ->setMaxResults(50);

        $logs = $qry->getQuery()->getResult();
        dump($logs); die();
```

The schema part that this query utilizes, is a I guess a parallel relationship as Hflog doesn't contain a relation to locations, instead I am using a connector table, which is specific to Hflog locations only.

[image]

The Doctrine annotaions for HflogSwlocations:

```
/**
     * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Hflogs
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Hflogs")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="hflog_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     * @SerialGroups({"public"})
     *
     */
    private $hflog;

/**
 * @var \AppBundle\Entity\SwLocations
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\SwLocations")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="sw_loc_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 * @SerialGroups({"public"})
 *
 */
private $swLoc;
```

returns this:

```
array:51 [▼
  0 => Hflogs {#450 ▶}
  1 => HflogSwLocations {#569 ▶}
  2 => HflogSwLocations {#413 ▶}
  3 => HflogSwLocations {#420 ▶}
  4 => HflogSwLocations {#437 ▶}
  5 => HflogSwLocations {#558 ▶}
  6 => HflogSwLocations {#555 ▶}
  7 => HflogSwLocations {#442 ▶}
  8 => HflogSwLocations {#584 ▶}
  9 => HflogSwLocations {#587 ▶}
```

HflogSwLocations belongs to HFlogs.

I can get what I need but the way that the results are provided seem unintuitive to me. If a Hflogs has a HflogSwLocations, I want Hflogs to be returned with HFlogSwLocations encapsulated as part of the relational entity. How do I accomplish this with a Doctrine query?

Comment: Take a look at how to do left joins with DQL.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to specify that you want to retrieve `'a'` in your query. All you need to do is to retrieve HfLogs. [Then it's all about lazy loading](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/extra-lazy-associations.html#enabling-extra-lazy-associations).

Comment: What do you mean by not retrieveing 'a'? Leave it out of the select method? Should I bother with the leftJoin method?

Comment: In your select() in your query builder, you are selecting the HfLogs (aliased by 'l' and  some locations  (aliased by 'a'). You don't need to do the leftJoin neither having the 'a' mention in your select list. Just get your HfLogs. Then, when you will access your HfLogs properties, you will have the locations available directly on your objects.

Comment: Could you provide me with a rewrite of my query build?